# How can the Redux action be observed?

Tags: reactjs, events, redux, react-redux, observer-pattern

I have Redux store with actions:

```
  const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case SAVE_ORDER_SUCCESS:
                return {...state,
                    order: action.data.order,
                    completedActionType: SAVE_ORDER,
                    completionStatus: SUCCESS,

                }
            case RECALC_ORDER_SUCCESS:
                return {...state,
                    order: action.data.order,
                    completedActionType: RECALC_ORDER,
                    completionStatus: SUCCESS,
                }
            case SAVE_ORDER_ERROR:
                return {...state,
                    order: action.data.order,
                    completedActionType: SAVE_ORDER,
                    completionStatus: ERROR,
                }   
        }       
    }
```

My React app usually calls those actions after completion of the request to the server - in the case when there was successfull execution on the server or in the case when server returned some error. I would like to complete those actions (e.g. SAVE_ORDER_SUCCESS) by showing success or error alerts (e.g. using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-alert), that automatially fades off, i.e., I would like to complete those actions by the call like `this.props.alert.show('...some message...');`. Of course, I can try to make this call as the last statement in my SAVE_ORDER_SUCCESS and other actions but I feel that it is bad: I guess that Redux actions should be nonvisual and noninteractive and that it would be far better that the UI component would listen to the completion of some action and the component could call `alert.show(...)` in the event listener to such action events. But is there patterns how can I create event listeners in the React component or function-component and how can I register those event listeners with the Redux actions and how such event listeners could observe the completion of Redux action.

Does my intention have some sense and is there React pattern for such event/listener/observer model?

Of course, one is tempted to use `state.completedActionType` and `state.completionStatus` in the `getDerivedStateFromProps()` of the component but it is not leading very far, because one should track those values by comparing them with the previous values (that could be stored in the local state of the component) and in such case there is no working scenario in the case of multiple consequtive success of error operations.

I am aware of the [Emitting events from Redux reducers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138287/emitting-events-from-redux-reducers) (unfortunately, that great question has received so little attention) with the idea about custom event array but I guess that some more standard pattern should exist.

There is https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener method, but it has no argument, it can be used for detecting changes in the state, but I can not see how one can see which action has been executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added `completionTime: new Date()` to each of my actions and then Component's componentDidUpdate did all the job:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.completionTime!=this.props.completionTime) {
      //do whatever needs to be done  
    }
}
```

As simple as that, no special observers. Of course, one can always introduce array of listeners in the store and then register listeners in this array and build up all this infrastructure, but I guess, `componentDidUpdate` is the right tool.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [redux-connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) ?